# metapost annotation

Tags: tikz-pgf, metapost

Metapost is a powerful tool for drawing, but not sure if it's more easier than tikz for annotation. Is it possible to draw this annotation graph with metapost?

tikz code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzstyle{boxa} = [top color=white,bottom color=blue!20!]
\tikzstyle{boxb} = [top color=white,bottom color=red!20!]
\tikzstyle{curly} = [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},xshift=0pt,yshift=2pt]                 
% Input:
%   #1 Line offset (optional)
%   #2 Line angle
%   #3 line start offset
%   #4 Line end offset
%   #5 Line label
% Example:
%   \lineann[1]{30}{1}{4}{$L_1$}
\newcommand{\lineann}[5][0.5]{%
    \begin{scope}[rotate=#2,blue,inner sep=2pt]
        \draw[dashed, blue!40] (#3,0) -- +(0,#1)
            node [coordinate, near end] (a) {};
        \draw[dashed, blue!40] (#4,0) -- +(0,#1)
            node [coordinate, near end] (b) {};
        \draw[|<->|] (a) -- node[fill=white] {#5} (b);
    \end{scope}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\def\dx{2.0}
\def\dy{.5}
\filldraw[thick,boxa] (0,0) rectangle node{$P_1$} +(\dx,\dy);
\filldraw[thick,boxa] (\dx,0) rectangle node{$P_2$} +(\dx,\dy);
\filldraw[thick,boxa] (2*\dx,0) rectangle node{$P_3$} +(\dx,\dy);
\filldraw[thick,boxb] (3*\dx,0) rectangle node{$P_4$} +(\dx,\dy);

\draw [curly] (0,\dy)--(4*\dx,\dy) node [black,midway,yshift=14pt] {\footnotesize $T_0$};
\lineann[-10pt]{0}{3*\dx}{4*\dx}{\footnotesize $T_1$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Easier" depends on your point of view and your experience of course, but there's no fundamental limitation in MP to prevent it drawing this type of diagram.

[image]

There are fewer complications built into plain MP than other tools, but that makes life simpler in some ways as there is less to learn.

I've shown two different approaches below.
For the brace label I've created a `brace_label` function, and for the arrow label I've just drawn it.  Creating a function requires a bit more work, but makes the main diagram source a bit easier to understand.

I've also used flat colours.  But there's nothing to stop you putting in gradients if you really want them - you just have to draw enough stripes gradually changing from one colour to another - not hard, just a bit tedious in plain MP - but again you could define (or find) a routine to do that for you if you wanted it often enough.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

vardef brace_label(expr s,a,b) text t_ = 
   save m,theta; pair m;
   theta := angle (b-a); m := .5[a,b]+(10 up rotated theta);
   label.top(s,m) rotatedabout(m, theta) t_;
   draw a+(2 up rotated theta) { dir (60+theta) }
       .. a+((6,6) rotated theta)
       -- m+((-6,-4) rotated theta)
       .. { dir (60+theta) } m { dir (theta-60) } 
       .. m+((+6,-4) rotated theta)
       -- b+((-6,6) rotated theta)
       .. { dir (theta-60) } b+(2 up rotated theta) 
       withpen pencircle scaled .4 t_;
enddef;

beginfig(1);

dx = 2cm; dy = dx/4;
path b[];
for i=1 upto 4: 
  b[i] = unitsquare xscaled dx yscaled dy shifted ((i-1)*dx,0); 
  fill b[i] withcolor .2[white, if i=4: red else: blue fi];
  draw b[i];
endfor

label(btex $P_1$ etex, center b1);
label(btex $P_2$ etex, center b2);
label(btex $P_3$ etex, center b3);
label(btex $P_4$ etex, center b4);

brace_label(btex $\scriptstyle T_0$ etex, ulcorner b1, urcorner b4);

drawoptions(withcolor .67 blue);
ahlength := 3;
path a; a = (llcorner b4 -- lrcorner b4) shifted 6 down;
drawdblarrow a;
draw llcorner b4 -- point 0 of a dashed withdots scaled .3;
draw lrcorner b4 -- point 1 of a dashed withdots scaled .3;
picture t; t = thelabel(btex $\scriptstyle T_1$ etex, point 1/2 of a);
unfill bbox t; draw t;
drawoptions();

endfig;
end.
```

Comment: Cool, but I get a error as below: mpost -tex=latex a.mp 
This is MetaPost, version 1.902 (TeX Live 2014) (kpathsea version 6.2.0)
(./a.mpfatal: Command failed: latex mpf7kM1Z.tex; see mpxerr.log
>> a.mp
>> a.mpx
! ! Unable to make mpx file.
l.28 label(btex
                $P_1$ etex, center b1);

Comment: Add verbatimtex sections for mpost compile error. not sure if it's right solution. how can I pass compile if without verbatimtex sections? Are you just using it in latex document?

Comment: @Beatlej Just compile it with `mpost` to make an eps file. Don't use latex as the tex engine.  Then include the eps file using `includegraphics`.

Comment: Great, so which case should we use latex as tex engine? I guess if we sue latex string in figure, we should use latex engine to compile!